# Yii2: has many на self. Почему зацикливание происходит?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, relation

Есть таблица пользователей. У каждого пользователя может быть лидер

```
id, leader_id и бла бла бла
```

хочу вывести всех пользователей, у кого я лидер

```
public function getTeam(){
     return $this->hasMany(self::className(), ['leader_id'=>'id']);
}
```

Происходит зацикливание. в базе данные следующие

```
id, name, leader_id
1, maxyc, null
2, smbname,1
3, smbname,1
4, smbname,1
5, smbname,1
```

Короч не вижу где моя беда

Answer (score 1):

Для решения вашей задачи необязательно использовать:

```
return $this->hasMany(...)
```

Можно воспользоваться обычным запросом на выборку:

```
public function getTeam(){
  if(!$this->isNewRecord)
    return static::findAll(['leader_id' => $this->id]);
 return [];
}
```